# A non-faithful 2 dimensional representation of the unique 2 dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I am trying to classify all 2 dimensional complex representations of the two dimensional non-abelian Lie Algebra $L$. This algebra has basis $\{x,y\}$ and the Lie bracket satisfies $[x,y]=x$.

Lets say that $V$ is a 2 dimensional representation of Lie algebra $L$ which is not faithful. I'm trying to show that then $x$ acts as zero on $V$ and that $V$ is completely described by the action of $y$.

From this, an "obvious corollary" is that there as many such representations as there are similarity classes of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices.

---

I feel like I've gotten tunnel vision on this one. I must have to get the Lie bracket involved somehow and show that if $x$ does have some non-trivial action on $V$ then the representation would be faithful... Which I think would mean that $y$ would have to act non trivially as well. I could use some help though!! Thanks

Comment: A representation which is non-faithful but also nontrivial must have kernel $L$? Wouldn't that make it a trivial representation?

Comment: No, it would make it what you said in the second paragraph: a representation on which $x$ acts as zero and $V$ is completely described by the action of $y$.

Comment: but if the kernel is $L$ wouldn't that mean that if $\gamma: L \rightarrow V$ is the representation that $\gamma(y) = 0$ ??? Seems trivial to me.

Comment: But $y$ is a basis vector of $L$

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry, I see what was confusing now. That was a typo (both times); I meant kernel the commutator ideal $[L, L] = \text{span}(x)$.

Comment: So, because the representation is nonfaithful it must have a nontrivial kernel. Since there is only 1 nontrivial ideal of the 2 dimensional abelian lie algebra, $L'$, we must have the kernel = $L' = span\{x\}$ and so the representation is completely determined by $y$... Did I miss anything important?

Comment: Nope, that's it.